# Airflow: continuously push to execution queue

Tags: airflow

I have a simple DAG that watches for new contents in a S3 bucket and triggers actions on those new contents:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import cached_property
from re import split

from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.triggers.s3 import S3KeyTrigger
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseOperator


BUCKET_KEY_WC = "master/*.jp2"
BUCKET_NAME = "imgconv-dev"


class DeferredS3KeySensor(BaseOperator):
    @cached_property
    def hook(self) -> S3Hook:
        return S3Hook(aws_conn_id=self.aws_conn_id)

    def __init__(
            self, bucket_key, bucket_name=None, aws_conn_id="aws_default",
            from_datetime=None, to_datetime=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.bucket_key = bucket_key
        self.aws_conn_id = aws_conn_id
        self.from_datetime = from_datetime
        self.to_datetime = to_datetime

    def execute(self, context):
        self.defer(
            trigger=S3KeyTrigger(
                bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY_WC,
                bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
                wildcard_match=True,
                aws_conn_id="s3_conn",
            ),
            method_name="_check_keys",
        )

    def _check_keys(self, context, event=None):
        bucket_name, key = S3Hook.get_s3_bucket_key(
                self.bucket_name, self.bucket_key, "bucket_name", "bucket_key")
        self.log.info(f"Looking for key pattern: s3://{bucket_name}/{key}")

        prefix = split(r"[\[\*\?]", key, 1)[0]
        key_matches = self.hook.list_keys(
                bucket_name=bucket_name,
                prefix=prefix,
                from_datetime=self.from_datetime,
                to_datetime=self.to_datetime,
                apply_wildcard=True) or []

        self.log.info(f"Key matches: {key_matches}")

        return key_matches


with DAG(
    dag_id="htj2k_convert",
    schedule=timedelta(minutes=1),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    tags=["drs", "media-proc"],
) as dag:

    @task
    def create_data(matching_keys):
        return [{"ref": val} for val in matching_keys]

    sensor = DeferredS3KeySensor(
        task_id="imgconv_watcher",
        bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY_WC,
        bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
        aws_conn_id="s3_conn",
        do_xcom_push=True,
    )

    processor = SimpleHttpOperator.partial(
        task_id="imgconv_processor",
        http_conn_id="imgconv_http_conn",
        endpoint="/convert/image/jp2_htj2k",
        method="POST",
    ).expand(data=create_data(sensor.output))

    sensor >> processor
```

this is working, but it has some shortcomings:

1. I created a custom operator (rather than using the pre-packaged `S3KeySensor`) because I need to only report keys that were added after the last successful check, so as not to re-process the files (the original files may be deleted after an indefinite time). However, there is no way that I know to tell which is the latest date/time that something got added.
2. The trigger runs frequently, and 99.9% of the times it doesn't find any files, but the whole DAG runs anyway and creates a lot of useless log entries that mix with the entries where work is actually done.

As a possible solution I thought about using two DAGs, the first one just polling S3 and pushing the file list somewhere, and the second one working on the list. This would have the added advantage that I can clean out the polling DAG logs more frequently and focus on the processing DAG.

I looked at datasets but I can't find a way for them to work, because I have to specify a static location. Files may be added and found by the polling DAG while another batch is still processing, so I cannot add files to the same data set.

I don't want to rely on AWS services to do the S3 polling for me because my S3 endpoint may not be on AWS.

Ideally I would want to push individual keys to a queue continuously, and have that feed the second DAG for processing.

Is there a way to do this? Or would you suggest another approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of resolved this by setting a timestamp just before the key lookup and writing it to a file only after a successful lookup; then reading the file at the next DAG run to determine which keys are new.

As for the task status, I was always getting "success" because in the code I posted I had not included a time filter, and the files were being reprocessed over and over. Adding the `from_datetime` filter caused the last task to be skipped, so it gives me some more at-a-glance information of what actually performed any work on the files.

Still, I'd like to split up the DAGs and maybe using the timestamp file as a dataset to trigger the second DAG.

If somebody has a more elegant solution, I'll be glad to hear it and select it as the accepted answer.

New version:

```py
import logging

from datetime import timedelta
from functools import cached_property
from os import makedirs, path
from re import split

from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.triggers.s3 import S3KeyTrigger
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseOperator
from pendulum import datetime, from_timestamp, now


BUCKET_KEY_WC = "master/*.jp2"
BUCKET_NAME = "imgconv-dev"
TS_FNAME = "/opt/airflow/dags/files/poll_ts"


class DeferredS3KeySensor(BaseOperator):
    @cached_property
    def hook(self) -> S3Hook:
        return S3Hook(aws_conn_id=self.aws_conn_id)

    def __init__(
            self, bucket_key, bucket_name=None, aws_conn_id="aws_default",
            **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.bucket_key = bucket_key
        self.aws_conn_id = aws_conn_id

    def execute(self, context):
        self.defer(
            trigger=S3KeyTrigger(
                bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY_WC,
                bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
                wildcard_match=True,
                aws_conn_id="s3_conn",
            ),
            method_name="_check_keys",
        )

    def _check_keys(self, context, event=None):
        # Set timestamp now before the lookup begins.
        this_ts = now("UTC")

        try:
            self.log.info(f"Reading timestamp from {path.realpath(TS_FNAME)}")
            with open(TS_FNAME, "r") as fh:
                prev_ts = from_timestamp(float(fh.read()))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            prev_ts = None

        bucket_name, key = S3Hook.get_s3_bucket_key(
                self.bucket_name, self.bucket_key, "bucket_name", "bucket_key")
        self.log.info(f"Looking for key pattern: s3://{bucket_name}/{key}")
        self.log.info(f"Looking for keys created after: {prev_ts.isoformat()}")

        prefix = split(r"[\[\*\?]", key, 1)[0]
        key_matches = self.hook.list_keys(
                bucket_name=bucket_name,
                prefix=prefix,
                from_datetime=prev_ts,
                apply_wildcard=True) or []

        self.log.info(f"Key matches: {key_matches}")

        makedirs(path.dirname(TS_FNAME), exist_ok=True)
        # Only persist timestamp after a successful pull (empty or not).
        with open(TS_FNAME, "w") as fh:
            fh.write(str(this_ts.timestamp()))

        return key_matches


with DAG(
    dag_id="htj2k_convert",
    schedule=timedelta(minutes=1),
    # schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    tags=["drs", "media-proc"],
) as dag:

    @task
    def create_data(matching_keys):
        logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")
        logger.info(f"Sensor XCom: {matching_keys}")
        return [{"ref": val} for val in matching_keys]

    sensor = DeferredS3KeySensor(
        task_id="imgconv_watcher",
        bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY_WC,
        bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
        aws_conn_id="s3_conn",
        do_xcom_push=True,
    )

    processor = SimpleHttpOperator.partial(
        task_id="imgconv_processor",
        http_conn_id="imgconv_http_conn",
        endpoint="/convert/image/jp2_htj2k",
        method="POST",
    ).expand(data=create_data(sensor.output))

    sensor >> processor
```